# Conditionally applying factor values from one dataframe to another

Tags: r

I have the following two data frames:

```
letters <- LETTERS[seq(from = 1, to = 5)]
values <- rnorm(5, mean = 50)
df1 <- data.frame(letters, values)

category <- sample(LETTERS[1:5], 20, replace = TRUE)
numbers <- rnorm(20, mean = 100)
df2 <- data.frame(category, numbers)
```

I want to create a new column in `df2` that takes the value in `df2$numbers` and subtracts the value in `df1$values` based on the matching letter.

In other words, if the value for "C" in `df1` is 49.2, I want to subtract 49.2 from every row in `df2$numbers` where `df$category` equals "C". Hope that makes sense. Thanks for the help!

Comment: `df2$numbers = df2$numbers - df1$values[match(df2$category, df1$letters)]`

Comment: worked beautifully, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

With `dplyr`:

```
df <- full_join(df1, df2, by = c('letters' = 'category')) %>% 
    mutate(diff = numbers - values)
```